# echo $a['id'] == $select ? blocks execution of the rest of the line

Tags: php, foreach

I have a strange result when trying to use a condition inside foreach loop.
In a simple array, I would like to point to a specific row (in that case #3).
`

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Peter'),
    array('id' => 2,'name' => 'Ben'),
    array('id' => 3,'name' => 'Joe'),
    array('id' => 4,'name' => 'Smith'),
    array('id' => 5,'name' => 'Josh'),
);

$select = 3; 

echo "<br/><br/>";

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    echo $a['id'] == $select ? '->' : "" . '&nbsp; "value="' . $a["id"] . '&nbsp;"name"=' . $a["name"] . "<br/>";
};

echo "<br/><br/>";

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    echo '&nbsp; "value="' . $a["id"] . '&nbsp;"name"=' . $a["name"] . "<br/>";
};
```

The result is as follows:

```
//First foreach with selection mark
  "value="1 "name"=Peter
      "value="2 "name"=Ben
    ->  "value="4 "name"=Smith
      "value="5 "name"=Josh
    
    //Second foreach
      "value="1 "name"=Peter
      "value="2 "name"=Ben
      "value="3 "name"=Joe
      "value="4 "name"=Smith
      "value="5 "name"=Josh`
```

Any idea is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Because you're not echoing the rest of the line. If true, echo `'->'`, otherwise, echo the rest. Break it up into two echo lines, or put parenthesis around your ternary

Comment: Its only going to return one value. when your on id 3 it's only going to return the '->'. So your record is not printed. Add a second echo to print the record. change the first to return '->' or ''.

Comment: `($select ? '->' : "")`

Comment: Many thanks to all!!! solution of @AbraCadaver works perfect.
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    echo ($a['id'] = $select ? '->' : "") . '&nbsp; "value="' . $a["id"] . '&nbsp;"name"=' . $a["name"] . "<br/>";
};